# Blender 3D 2.8 Push Pull: How to use it?

Tags: user-interface, blender

I'm trying (with difficulty) to learn Blender3D 2.80 using LinkedIn Learning's 2.7-compatible documentation (which is great, don't get me wrong, but it's very out of date after this massive UI upgrade).

Specifically I am trying to figure out how to use the push-pull tool in Edit mode on subdivided faces. I've subdivided the top face of a cube and extruded each individual face upward. Now I'm trying to figure out how to use the push-pull tool to make each face move away from the center. The new UI has a tool on the left side that can be switched from Shrink/Fatten to Push/Pull.

There are two problems I'm trying to solve. The first is how to tell the push/pull not to resize each face but instead to spread them out without distorting or scaling them, away from the selected center point (the 3D cursor). Optimally I'd like to be able to define a specific size for the gap between the faces. If I drag on the selected faces, the whole top of the object spreads out as a whole, like a mushroom.

The second is that there doesn't seem to be a numerical entry field for specifying the amount of the push pull in the sidebar. Where would this be now that the tool has changed so much?

Thanks for any input in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Push/Pull](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/push_pull.html) tool will either push the selected items towards each other or pull them away from each other.

To move things in a specific direction, you want the [move tool (sometimes called translate)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/move_rotate_scale.html). You can use the <kbd>G</kbd> shortcut and enter a numeric amount to move. You can also press <kbd>F9</kbd> to [adjust the amount](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation) after you have moved.